# Is there a way to access the color property on the standard mobile diffuse shader?

Tags: ios, mobile, unity-game-engine

I'm having some problems using the color property on the standard mobile diffuse shader in Unity. I want to be able to have a flat white texture and change the color via code, but it looks like that shader doesn't have the main color property. I could use a standard (i.e. non mobile) shader, but I wonder if that could be a problem for performance.
So: can I access the color property on the mobile shader? If not, is there some very simple 3rd party mobile shader that will allow me to do that?

Answer (score 0):

That's intended, mobile shaders are performing better on mobile but have less features. If you must use the color property then use the regular shader, don't worry too much about performance unless there's a real performance issue!

Comment: I will do that. I tend to be very careful with performances on mobile, but to be honest an iPhone5 can handle way more complicated things that I can possibly create :)